# Как правильно сказать: "антипятин" или "антипятнин"?

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь

Как правильно сказать: "антипятин" или "антипятнин" — с точки зрения норм русского языка?

Comment: Я за второй вариант. Первый мог предложить разве что Антип Ятин :) .

Answer (score 1):

Слово *антипят(н)ин* не фиксируется словарями, однако в интернете можно найти информацию о гигиеническом средстве "Антипятин".

*Антипятнин* не столь благозвучно, как *антипятин* (из-за сочетания *тн*), поэтому, как видно, предпочтение отдается второму варианту.

Answer (score 0):

Вы намекаете, что сохранение корня *-пятн-* было бы правильным при образовании сложного слова... Совершенно справедливо, однако слова не всегда придумываются ценителями языка, и это — проза жизни. Да и поэзия тоже.